# zurb foundation targeting nested ol ul list

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to have the 2nd part of the nested ol have alphabet list items but it's all appearing as numbers. How do I change it to have a) and b) in the second nested part ?

```
            <p>This is some texts:<br>
              <ol>
                <ol>
                  <li class=first list item.</li>

                  <li class="list-numbers">second list item</li>
                 </ul>

                Some text

                <ol class="list-alphabet">

                <li class="list-alphabet">first list item second part.</li>

                <li class="list-alphabet">second list item second part</li>
                </ol>
              </ol>
</div>


ol.alphabet li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}

.alphabet ol li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}

ol-.alphabet li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}

ol li ol li.alphabet {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}

ol li ol li. {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/setbon/gGEKH/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mixed up your CSS *'list-alphabet / alphabet'* names.

Updated code

```
<p>This is some texts:</p>
<br>
<ol>
   <ol>
    <li>first list item.</li>
    <li>second list item</li>Some text
    <ol class="alphabet">
        <li>first list item second part.</li>
        <li>second list item second part</li>
    </ol>
   </ol>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol.alphabet li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}
```